# Disable C++ warning at project level?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, visual-c++-2008

I know you can use a `#pragma` to disable a warning in a specific file, but I want to "turn off" a certain warning for a whole VC++ 2008 project.

I found an option `Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Disable Specific Warnings` but when I entered the numeric warning code and re-compiled the .cpp file in question, the warning was still generated.

Comment: Did you write the warning number with the "C" in front like "C4244" or just the number "4244" ?

Comment: If I put the 'C', the compiler gives an error.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, and adding a comment here: no precompiled header is used.

Comment: For me it works when entering something like this: "4244;4996;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)". Perhaps you have pragmas in your code which enable the warning again?

Comment: This option works for me with VC2017.

Answer (score 2):

If your project includes other projects or uses objects from another project, make sure you add the warning disable on the project where the warning occurs. This should always work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use precompiled header and put warnings disable code there. It worked for me with warning C4005.